# What is "__static_initialization_and_destruction_0" and how to solve the issue?

Tags: c++

My code works fine with small numbers when `dp[105][x]` when i keep `x` small. But when `long long` input comes i need to change the `x` to larger value greater than `10^9` then this error comes
`` /tmp/cc35Ue0y.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)': main.cpp:(.text+0x294): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' main.cpp:(.text+0x2a3): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' ``if i dont change it gives segmentation fault.
My code is for Atcode DP contest E problem https://atcoder.jp/contests/dp/tasks/dp_e

code :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int n, v[105];
long long int wt[105] , W, dp[105][105];


long long int fun(int n, long long int W, long long int wt[], int v[]) {
    
    if(n == 0 || W == 0) return 0;
    
    if(dp[n][W] != -1) return dp[n][W];
    if(wt[n] <= W) {
        return dp[n][W] = max(v[n] + fun(n-1, W - wt[n], wt, v), fun(n-1, W, wt, v)); 
    }
    else {
        return dp[n][W] = fun(n-1, W, wt, v);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cin >> n >> W;
    // for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
    //     for(int j=0;j<2;j++) {
    //         cin >> a[i][j];
    //     }
    // }
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
        cin >> wt[i] >> v[i];
    }
    memset(dp, -1, sizeof(dp));
    cout << fun(n, W, wt, v);
    return 0;
}
```

What changes do i need to make.

Comment: Are you sure you will have enough space for `105*10**9*sizeof(long long)` bytes?

Comment: I too dont think i need to change that x part but dont know how

Comment: Please, provide a complete compilation command, compiler info (vendor, version), and architecture info.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57331990/580083

Comment: I dont know what u mean but u can copy my code to ur compiler or any online will work too. and run for ```1 1000000000
1000000000 10
``` u will get the errors

Comment: *"Memory Limit: 1024 MB"*

Answer (score 2):

Stack is generally limited, use dynamic memory to handle that, as `std::vector`

or `auto dp = new std::array<std::array<long long int, 105>, 1'000'000'000>;`

but size seems even huge for heap...

You probably have to change your algorithm.

Comment: But `dp` should not be stored on the stack.

Comment: could u make the changes in my code and post it